# About a Proof of Quadratic Reciprocity Law

Tags: number-theory

I have a doubt on [a proof of Quadratic Reciprocity law given by G. Rousseau](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/quickSearch?quickSearchType=search_combined&inputField1=on+the+quadratic+reciprocity+law+rousseau&fieldStartMonth=01&fieldStartYear=1800&fieldEndMonth=12&fieldEndYear=2011&searchType=ADVANCESEARCH&searchTypeFrom=quickSearch&fieldScjrnl=All&fieldSccats=All&selectField1=%23&jnlId=&journalSearchType=all).

In this paper I am unable to understand the fact that $\{ (i, j) : i= 1,2,\ldots,p-1 ; j =1,2,\ldots, q-1/2 \}$ is a system of representatives for the cosets of $U$. 
But how these elements turns out to be an representatives of the cosets?

Comment: I got the answer..

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\{(i,j) : i = 1, \ldots p-1; j= 1, \ldots, q-1\}$ is a set of coset representatives for the full group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times \times (\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^\times$.  Suppose we have a representative $(i,j)$ for a coset of $U$ with $i \in \{1, \ldots, p-1\}$ and $j \in \{1, \ldots, q-1\}$ but with $j$ outside the range $1, \ldots, (q-1)/2$, so $\frac{q+1}{2} \leq j \leq q-1$.  Since $(-1,-1) \in U$, then
$$
(i,j) \equiv (i,j)(-1,-1) = (-i, -j) \equiv (p-i, q-j) \pmod{U} .
$$
Moreover, note that $p-i \in \{1, \ldots, p-1\}$ and
$$
1 \leq q-j \leq q - \frac{q+1}{2} = \frac{q-1}{2}
$$
as desired.